# xcode6 - admob properties has previous declaration

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, xcode6, admob

i want to use adMob in my project because iAds interstitialAds stretch my spriteNodes for some reason after they disapear but i´m getting a few errors:
(i tried to clean my build folder already)

```
//
//  GADInterstitial.h
//  Google Mobile Ads SDK
//
//  Copyright 2011 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADInAppPurchaseDelegate.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADInterstitialDelegate.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADRequest.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADRequestError.h>

/// An interstitial ad. This is a full-screen advertisement shown at natural transition points in
/// your application such as between game levels or news stories.
///
/// Interstitials are shown sparingly. Expect low to no fill.
@interface GADInterstitial : NSObject

#pragma mark Pre-Request

/// Required value created on the AdMob website. Create a new ad unit for every unique placement of
/// an ad in your application. Set this to the ID assigned for this placement. Ad units are
/// important for targeting and statistics.
///
/// Example AdMob ad unit ID: @"ca-app-pub-0123456789012345/0123456789"
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *adUnitID;

/// Optional delegate object that receives state change notifications from this GADInterstitalAd.
/// Remember to nil this property before deallocating the delegate.
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<GADInterstitialDelegate> delegate;

/// Optional delegate object that receives in-app purchase notifications from this ad. Required for
/// the custom in-app purchase flow, but ignored when using the default in-app purchase flow.
/// Remember to nil this property before deallocating the delegate.
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<GADInAppPurchaseDelegate> inAppPurchaseDelegate;

#pragma mark Making an Ad Request

/// Makes an interstitial ad request. Additional targeting options can be supplied with a request
/// object. Only one interstitial request is allowed at a time.
///
/// This is best to do several seconds before the interstitial is needed to preload its content.
/// Then when transitioning between view controllers show the interstital with
/// presentFromViewController.
- (void)loadRequest:(GADRequest *)request;

#pragma mark Post-Request

/// Returns YES if the interstitial is ready to be displayed. The delegate's
/// interstitialAdDidReceiveAd: will be called after this property switches from NO to YES.
@property(nonatomic, readonly, assign) BOOL isReady;

/// Returns YES if this object has already been presented. Interstitial objects can only be used
/// once even with different requests.
@property(nonatomic, readonly, assign) BOOL hasBeenUsed;

/// Returns the ad network class name that fetched the current ad. Returns nil while the latest ad
/// request is in progress or if the latest ad request failed. For both standard and mediated Google
/// AdMob ads, this method returns @"GADMAdapterGoogleAdMobAds". For ads fetched via mediation
/// custom events, this method returns @"GADMAdapterCustomEvents".
@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *adNetworkClassName;

/// Presents the interstitial ad which takes over the entire screen until the user dismisses it.
/// This has no effect unless isReady returns YES and/or the delegate's interstitialDidReceiveAd:
/// has been received.
///
/// Set rootViewController to the current view controller at the time this method is called. If your
/// application does not use view controllers pass in nil and your views will be removed from the
/// window to show the interstitial and restored when done. After the interstitial has been removed,
/// the delegate's interstitialDidDismissScreen: will be called.
- (void)presentFromRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController;

@end
```

for @interface i get this error: duplicate interface definition

and for every @property i get this: Property has a previous declaration

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have two copies of GoogleMobileAdsSdk in your project. Delete one of them. Make sure you have the latest SDK from [AdMob](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download). Then implement the AdMob interstitial like so.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
// Import AdMob framework in your header file
// #import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>

// Enter YOUR ad id you receive from AdMob here
#define INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID @"yourAdMobInterstitialID"

@interface ViewController () <GADInterstitialDelegate>
@end

@implementation ViewController {
    // AdMob
    GADInterstitial *adMobInterstitial;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // AdMob
    adMobInterstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    adMobInterstitial.adUnitID = INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID;
    [adMobInterstitial loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}

// Call this method when you want to show an ad
// [self showAdMobInterstitial];
-(void)showAdMobInterstitial {
    // Lets present the ad
    adMobInterstitial.delegate = self;
    [adMobInterstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
    NSLog(@"adMobInterstitial presentFromRootViewController");
}

-(void)interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
    // Failed to receive ad from AdMob
    // Lets get another ad for the next time we would like to show one
    adMobInterstitial = nil;
    adMobInterstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    adMobInterstitial.adUnitID = INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID;
    [adMobInterstitial loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
    NSLog(@"didFailToReceiveAdWithError");
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

-(void)interstitialWillDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {
    NSLog(@"interstitialWillDismissScreen");
}

-(void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {
    // User received ad and has closed it
    // Lets get another ad for the next time we would like to show one
    adMobInterstitial = nil;
    adMobInterstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    adMobInterstitial.adUnitID = INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID;
    [adMobInterstitial loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
    NSLog(@"interstitialDidDismissScreen");
}
```

Comment: so far it seems to work thank you, but i still get this log: <Google> Cannot present interstitial. It is not ready.

Comment: so i tried this delegate-method and it fire´s the ad immediately after load the viewController: ` -(void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)ad{
    [adMobInterstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
    NSLog(@"adMobInterstitial didReceiveAd");
}  ` but why cant i fire it manually, this won´t work ??

Comment: @NeoGER89 You're getting ` <Google> Cannot present interstitial. It is not ready. ` because you are attempting to present the ad too soon. You need to give it a few seconds to load before calling `[self showAdMobInterstitial]`. Call it after a user does something. Not when the app first loads. `-(void)interstitialDidReceiveAd` is not meant to be called directly. This is called by your `GADInterstitial` when it successfully receives an ad so you can do things to prepare your app for presenting an ad. For example, saving game state, pausing sounds, disabling timers, etc.

Comment: i tried when i press the play button after waiting about 10 sec. its not working, i tried to fire it after the user succesfully signed in to gamecenter. doesn´t work eiter. the only way i get the ad to show up is in the delegate method. i dont know why. i also tried to show the ad up after the delegate already shows it up. the only way it shows up on and on is as a loop. for example in the interstitialdiddismiss method, in it i send a new request and then when i dismiss the ad, a new one shows up.